# Convert FFmpeg command to GStreamer pipeline parse image from rtsp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to convert the working FFmpeg command to a GStreamer pipeline to extract image from the RTSP stream.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v error -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 10000000 -i 'rtsp://{domain}/Streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20220831T103000Z&endtime=20220831T103010Z' -vframes 1 -y image.jpg
```

Here is the GStreamer pipeline I tried to convert:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://{domain}/Streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20220831T103000Z&endtime=20220831T103010Z" max-rtcp-rtp-time-diff=0 latency=0 is_live=true drop-on-latency=true ! decodebin3 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc snapshot=true ! filesink location="/mnt/c/images/frame3.jpg"
```

I couldn't manage to get it working. It gives the wrong timestamp image and the Gstreamer pipeline never stopped after extracting the image just working like an infinite loop.

But the FFmpeg command works perfect and extracts the correct image and quits from the command after successfully extracting the image.

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding imagefreeze with num-buffers=1:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc protocols=tcp location="rtsp://{domain}/Streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20220831T103000Z&endtime=20220831T103010Z" max-rtcp-rtp-time-diff=0 latency=0 is-live=true drop-on-latency=true ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! imagefreeze num-buffers=1 ! jpegenc snapshot=true ! filesink location="/mnt/c/images/frame3.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks @Seb it works, terminates the command after extracting the image but it still returns the wrong timestamp image.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add TCP transport as your ffmpeg command does. You may tell how you get timestamps and compare. You may try various properties of rtspsrc :`gst-inspect-1.0 rtspsrc` such as `buffer-mode`